# symbolic modulo operation in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, modulo

In my old 2007 Matlab code, I was doing modulo operation on symbolic varaibles as follows:

```
syms x
if (mod(5*x, x) == 0)
     in = 1
end
```

Today I ran the same program in R2013a and I am getting

```
mod(5*x, x)= x*(5 mod x)
```

Due to this result, the `if` condition is not passed. As a result, my program is aborting.

I am not able to understand the reasons for this. I appreciate your comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a minimal example that reproduces the problem. For example, your code snippet does not define the value of `x`

Comment: Thanks, Luis for your attention. I was expecting that by default it could evaluate. without assigning any numerical  value. However, I had changed the if condition as follows:

`if(  isequal(5*x/coeffs(5*x),x)   )
 in = 1
end`

this new lines of code work like charm.